# Object overlapping issue for SVG in IE10-11

Tags: svg

I am facing some issue with object overlapping with SVG in IE 10 and IE 11.
To understand this problem i have created one html file with simple rectangle and line. We have used SVG to draw line element.
Here half of the line is being displayed, but rest of the line that is overlapping the rectangle is not visible even though the z-index of line is higher than rectangle.

Here is the content of HTML file,

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<line id="2" style="z-index:2; position:absolute;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:3px;" x1="990" y1="242" x2="567" y2="242"></line>
</svg>
<div ID="1" height="277">
<table id="1_rectangle" type="rectangle" height="277" style="position: absolute;top: 129;left: 242;width: 567;border: 1 solid #000000;color: #000000;color: #000000;background-color: #ffff00;border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed;z-index:1;background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffff00 0%, #ffff00 100%);">
<tr>
<td height="277"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<body>

<div style="position: relative; z-index:2; margin-top:300px; margin-left:100px; ">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <line x1="0" y1="10" x2="300" y2="10"  style="stroke:#000000; stroke-width:15px;"/>
    </svg>
</div>

<div ID="1" height="277">
<table id="1_rectangle" type="rectangle" height="277" style="position: absolute;top: 129;left: 242;width: 567;border: 1 solid #000000;color: #000000;color: #000000;background-color: #ffff00;border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed;z-index:1;background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffff00 0%, #ffff00 100%);">
<tr>
<td height="277"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay.. That Works..
But here lets say for multiple lines each with different z-index and position we will have to add <Div> tag with <SVG> tag inside for each.
Is there any solution for that multiple <svg> tag in that case??